# Finding order of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to find the order, i.e. smallest $k\in \mathbb{N}, k>1$ s.t. $A^k=I$, of the following matrix where arithmetic is over $\mathbb{Z}_2$:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots 0\\
0&0&1&\cdots 0\\
\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots 1 \\
1&1&1&\cdots1
 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

I've looked at a few $n$ and looks like the order is $n+1$ but I am not sure how to prove that? Any ideas? I see that with increasing power by one shifts original rows of $A$ up by one and adds rows corresponding to the identity matrix. For example, for $n=4$:

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&1 \\
1&0&0&0
 \end{bmatrix},A^3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0
 \end{bmatrix},A^4=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0
 \end{bmatrix},A^5=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1
 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: The computations are not correct. Already $A^2$ is different!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I forgot mentioning that arithmetic is over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: This is a very important change, of course!

Comment: I think you may be able to use the fact that this is the transpose of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) for $x^n + x^{n-1} + \cdots + x + 1 = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x - 1}$. (Note that $-1=1$ mod $2$.) That at least shows that the order of $A$ divides $n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the finite field $\Bbb F_2$ the order of $A\in GL_n(\Bbb F_2)$ is $n+1$. Indeed, the row $(1,1\cdots ,1)$ is rising up one level after each multiplication with $A$. So $A^{n+1}=I$ and $A^n\neq I$. Formally, let $(e_1,\ldots ,e_n)$ be a basis. Then compute $A^{n+1}(e_i)$ for each $i=1,\ldots ,n$.

Over a field of characteristic zero, $A$ has infinite order.

Comment: I see, thanks, it's been a while since I've looked at abstract algebra. Is there a general formula for order an element in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Comment: The order of $A\in GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$ has to divide $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2)\cdots (p^n-p^{n-1})$ by Lagrange.

Comment: I see, that's because order of the group $GL_n(\mathbb{F})_p$ is what you have above and by Lagrange's theorem, order of any subgroup divides the order of the original group?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A general formula is difficult, since it depends on the  matrix.

Comment: Thanks, how do we know that $n+1$ divides $(2^n-1)(2^n-2)\cdots(2^n-2^{n-1})$?

Comment: By induction. For $n=2$ it is clear since $3\mid (2^2-1)$.

Comment: I see, how do we know which divisor of $(2^n-1)\cdots (2^n-2^{n-1})$ is the order of $A$? Just wanted to know how you knew the answer was $n+1$ so fast, haha.

Comment: I followed up the basis vector $e_1$ under powers of $A$. So $Ae_1=e_n$, $A^2e_1=Ae_n=e_{n-1}+e_n$ and so on. Then the other basis vectors. From Lagrange you cannot derive which factor it is.

Answer (score 1):

for similar but more linear algebra oriented proof:

**i.)** $A$ is a Companion matrix of the polynomial $x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x+1$
**ii.)** By Cayley Hamilton $\mathbf 0 = A^n+A^{n-1}+...+A+I$
**iii.)** over any field, the minimal polynomial of a Companion matrix is the characteristic polynomial.  This implies the order of $A$ is $\gt n$.
**iv.)** 'Subtracting' (or adding since the field has characteristic two) $A^n$ from each side in (ii.), and then multiplying each side by $A$, we get
$A^{n+1}=A\big(A^n\big)= A\big(A^{n-1}+...+A+I\big)= A^{n}+A^{n-1}...+A=I$
where the final equality comes from adding $\mathbf 0 =\big(A^n+A^{n-1}+...+A+I\big) $ to $A^{n}+A^{n-1}...+A$